# Java Point Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

Write a comparator that compares Point objects by their distance from origin of (0,0).  Points that are closer to the origin are considered to come before those which are further from the origin.

I just wanted some input on if I'm on the right track here…and what I'm missing

```
public class PointComparator implements Comparator<Point> 
{
    public int compare(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        int dx = p1.x - p2.x;
        if (dx == 0){
            int dy = p1.y - p2.y;
            return dy;
        }else{
            return dx;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow sorry for the format of my code there, new to posting on here

Comment: I've edited your question to format the code properly.  Next time, please select your code in the editor and click the `{}` button to format as code.

Comment: Then go through the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). It will help you ask better questions and avoid downvotes.

Comment: You are comparing the x and y distances, not the distance from the origin. Think about your basic geometry first, then the solution should present itself.

Comment: You should calculate the distance to the origin for both points and compare them... How would you calculate distance to origin?

Comment: Which will your program say is closer to (0,0)? (2,2) or (1,100000000)?

Comment: if (-1,0) closer than (+1, 0) ?

Comment: Might I suggest the Pythagorean theorem to calculate distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the distance from the origin for the points, like:

```
double r1 = Math.sqrt(x1*x1 + y1*y1)
```

Pay attention to double, it is not an int. Then:

```
return Double.compare(r1, r2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The distance between the point and the origin is sqrt(x squared + y squared). Calculate that value for both points and take the difference for your comparison.

Comment: You can also escape the asterisks like `\*`.

Comment: int dx = sqrt(p1.x^2 + p1.y^2);
  int dy = sqrt(p2.x^2 + p2.y^2);
  
  return dx - dy;

Comment: Is this on the right track? By the way I appreciate everyone's input so far, I can see how useful this website will be for me moving forward

Comment: @Moondude like Lumberjack points out, you're dealing with double, not int, and can take advantage of the built in comparator for Double.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you are doing is comparing to points together instead of comparing it with the origin. So its better you understand what you want before coding.
Anyway the distance between two points with coordinates (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is
                    **sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)**
one of the coordinates in your case would be (0,0) i.e. origin.

Comment: public int compare(Point p1, Point p2)
     {
  double p1 = Math.sqrt(x1*x1 + y1*y1);

  double p2 = Math.sqrt(x2*x2 + y2*y2);
  
  return Double.compare(p1, p2);
 }